# WPF open new window on another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In the code below, I call method that opens a custom new window. However when application is doing some long running task I wish to still be able to activate the window. Is it possible to do it on another thread or by using the `Task` class?

```
public static class CustomW
{
    static Custom_Window_Chrome_Demo.ThemedWindow MsgBox(string Msgbx_TTL, string Msgbx_Contnt)
    {
        var w_mbx = new Custom_Window_Chrome_Demo.ThemedWindow();
        w_mbx.Width = 950; w_mbx.Height = 159;
        w_mbx.Title = Msgbx_TTL;

        Grid g = new Grid();
        StackPanel spM = new StackPanel();
        TextBlock TblckErrMsg = new TextBlock();
       //more settings......
    } 
}
```

This is how I tried to invoke it,

```
public void newMsgBoxShow(string Msgbx_TTL, string Msgbx_Contnt)
{
    System.Threading.Thread s = new System.Threading.Thread( 
       ()=>
        CustomW.MsgBox(Msgbx_TTL, Msgbx_Contnt).Show()
       );
}
```

but when I am using the new thread I am getting the following error.

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this

What is the correct way to achieve the required result ?

Comment: Where is the long-running task?

Comment: Well you should run your long task on another threads and main tread leave for UI and non-heavy stuff.

Comment: @NicoSchertler the long task is searching DB long code..

Comment: As suggested you should do your long running task on another thread, perhaps with a background worker. See here for explanations: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/841751/MultiThreading-Using-a-Background-Worker-Csharp

Comment: @NawedNabiZada then I try the same (calling `CustomW.MsgBox()` )from the new thread same results

Comment: You don't have access to your main thread from the background worker. Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( ()=> {CustomW.MsgBox()}); will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
            {
                //your window code
            }), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

When new thread is created with **Current Synchronization context** it will be able to update the UI.(when current thread is UI thread)

**You can also use dispatcher to execute your code.**

```
 System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
            {
                //your window code
            }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Dispatcher

https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(delegate { /* CODE */ }, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```